# Sum of MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a MySQL DB

I would like to get the sum or totals of values in my columns I need to echo it to be used in Google Graphs

This is my current code

```
 <?php 
        $query = "SELECT * from activation";

         $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

         echo "['".$row['type']."',".$sum['type']."],"; 
         }
         ?>
```

The row Type is the ones I want to get SUM on their values differ from HIJACKING ACCIDENT and so forth values are constant.

The $sum I know is wrong but this is where I need to echo the totals of row type

The following code worked

```
 <?php 
            $query = "SELECT type, count(type) from activation group by type";

             $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

             echo "['".$row['type']."',".$row['count(type)']."],";
             }
             ?>
```

Comment: why don't you `SUM()` *in* the query instead?

Comment: ^^ this or `$sum += $row['type'];` (initalize `$sum=0` before the while) - then `echo $sum`

Comment: How about `SELECT type, count(type) from activation group by type`?

Comment: your echo line looks like you try to construct a json string. Don't do that. Build an array, then json_encode that.

Comment: @Curious_Mind Your string gives me the results I need when I place in HeidiSQL but how will I echo the values then to the graph as per the echo?

Comment: @Curious_Mind Thank you I have added the correct code that works

Comment: @TrevorAckermann Best of Luck, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the more precise code that you should use. I used alias of your `count(type)` as `act_type`. Hope this helps :)

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT type, count(type) as act_type from activation group by type";
    $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $expected = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
         $expected[$row['type']] = $row['act_type'];
         echo "['".$row['type']."',".$row['act_type']."],"; // you can use this line just for printing purpose
   }
   // use $expected array as you wish any where in your code, it contains your result as key=>value manner
?>
```